# MongoDB SyntaxError: missing ] after element list

Tags: mongodb

The collection like this:

```
{"user1" : 1, "rate1" : 3, "user2" : 3, "rate2" : 2}
```

And the formula:

```
percent = sum(rate1*rate2)/(sqrt(sum(rate1))*sqrt(sum(rate2)))
```

Here is my code:

```
db.user_similarity.aggregate([
      { 
           $group :
           { 
             _id : 
             {
                "user1" : "$user1",
                "user2" : "$user2"
             },
             percent :
             {
                 $divide:
                 [
                    $sum: { $multiply: [ "$rate1", "$rate2" ] },
                    $multiply:
                    [
                        $sqrt:{$sum: { $multiply: [ "$rate1", "$rate1" ] }},
                        $sqrt:{$sum: { $multiply: [ "$rate2", "$rate2" ] }}
                     ]
                 ]
             }
           }
       },
       { $out : "similar_rate" }  
      ])
```

And the error like this:

```
E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ] after element list @(shell):14:20
```

Is there something wrong in the code？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is invalid JSON:

```
$divide:
[
    $sum: { $multiply: [ "$rate1", "$rate2" ] },
    $multiply:
    [
        $sqrt:{$sum: { $multiply: [ "$rate1", "$rate1" ] }},
        $sqrt:{$sum: { $multiply: [ "$rate2", "$rate2" ] }}
    ]
]
```

Should probably be:

```
$divide:
[
    { $sum: { $multiply: [ "$rate1", "$rate2" ] }},
    {
        $multiply:
        [
            {$sqrt:{$sum: { $multiply: [ "$rate1", "$rate1" ] }}},
            {$sqrt:{$sum: { $multiply: [ "$rate2", "$rate2" ] }}}
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "unknown group operator '$divide'", "code" : 15952 } the '$divide' can not be used in group ?